# Copy styles from template to many documents using Aspose.Words

Tags: java, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to create a Java “script” such that, given a template and a target document:

- reads all styles defined in the template, both for text and tables
- copies each style onto the target document, replacing the style if it already exists

To summarize, this is what I have come up until now, also based on the [API reference for the `StyleCollection` class](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/StyleCollection):

```
Document target = new Document(targetPath);
StyleCollection targetStyles = target.getStyles();

for (Style style : source.getStyles()) {
    switch (style.getType()) {
        case StyleType.PARAGRAPH:
        case StyleType.TABLE:
        case StyleType.LIST:
            if (!style.getName().trim().toLowerCase().endsWith("carattere")) {
                String name = style.getName();
                Style copied = styles.addCopy(style);

                switch (style.getType()) {
                    case StyleType.PARAGRAPH:
                        copied.setNextParagraphStyleName(style.getNextParagraphStyleName());
                        // fallthrough

                    case StyleType.CHARACTER:
                    case StyleType.TABLE:
                        copied.setBaseStyleName(style.getBaseStyleName());
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                copied.setName(name);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

target.save(savePath);
```

As of now, the problems I have identified are the following:

- if I tried using the standard MS Word styles (“Normal”, “Title 1”, …), when they’re copied over they get duplicated even using the setName() “trick”
- if I instead use custom style, I have a problem with table styles, in which the text color changes

How do I get a clean copy of all the styles in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I tried using the standard MS Word styles (“Normal”, “Title 1”, …),
>   when they’re copied over they get duplicated even using the setName()
>   “trick”

Please use following sample code snippet, it will help you to get output without style duplication.

```
Document source = new Document(MyDir + "template.doc");
Document target = new Document(MyDir + "target.doc");

StyleCollection sourceStyles = source.getStyles();
StyleCollection targetStyles = target.getStyles();

System.out.println("SORGENTE = " + sourceStyles.getCount() + " stili");
System.out.println("DESTINAZIONE = " + targetStyles.getCount() + " stili");

for (Style style : sourceStyles) {
    String name = style.getName();
    if (name.endsWith("Carattere")) continue;

    if (style.getType() == StyleType.PARAGRAPH
                            || style.getType() == StyleType.TABLE)
    {
        Style copied = targetStyles.addCopy(style);
        copied.setBaseStyleName(style.getBaseStyleName());

        if (style.getType() == StyleType.PARAGRAPH) {
           copied.setNextParagraphStyleName(style.getNextParagraphStyleName());
        }
        copied.setName(name);
        System.out.println("COPIA STILE " + name + " -> " + copied.getName());
    }
}

target.cleanup();
target.save(MyDir + "output.docx");
```

> if I instead use custom style, I have a problem with table styles, in
>   which the text color changes

Please note Aspose.Words mimics MS Word behavior. If you [import the styles from your template to target document using MS Word](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1004-word-import-styles.html), it will show same results as Aspose.Words does.

I work with Aspose as developer Evangelist.

Comment: I tried moving `copied.setName()` as the last step of the copy process, which is the only difference between my code and yours, result is still the same. And no, If I import the styles using native MS Word functionality, I get a different result.

Comment: I think I found the issue, it fails only for DOC files, while it works correctly for DOCX files.

Comment: I stand corrected on what I said: even after adding your suggested check on the style name, excluding all ending in "Carattere", still I find duplicates in the resulting document

Comment: Please share your output document. Please also share your code if it is different than above shared code and mention which input documents you used for this test, as you have shared three set of documents. We will look into the issue again and provide you information accordingly.

Comment: Here is a ZIP archive with a test template file, a target file, the merge result using the code I edited in my question and the expected result obtained after merging the styles using MS WORD directly: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hm5d6cfslge9i5/merge_style_test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please note there is another change in suggested code as well. Please use cleanup() method before saving the document. It removes unused lists and styles from the document. It will help you get expected document: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Ikp83eI1Y-bUlVS0JfRGtTb3c

Comment: Oh my, I really missed that line! I am sorry, I tried it again and now seems ok... sorry for taking you so much time, thanks for your help!